# How to render content queried with mongoose.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean-stack

First of all, I am using node.js, express.js, mongoose.js/mongodb.
I am trying to route traffic as follows:

```
app.get('/:username/:language', pageRoutes.fetchLanguage);
```

When I process the following queries, I seem to get the expected results (when I print to console.log I see the expected output). However, when I try to render the page in any way I get an error.

```
var User = require('./../models/user-model');
var Language = require('./../models/language-model');
var Element = require('./../models/element-model');

exports.fetchLanguage = function(req, res) {
    var target_lang = req.params.language;

    // Find the user by username, so that I can get their _id
    User.findOne({username: req.params.username}, {_id: 1}, function(err, userdoc){

        // This prints the _id as expected
        console.log(userdoc._id); 

        // Find all languages associated with that user _id
        // (just need a list of language names)
        Language.find({_user_id: userdoc._id}, {name: 1}, function(err, languages){

            // Find the one language that was requested
            Language.findOne({_user_id: userdoc._id, name: target_lang}).populate('sections.elements').exec(function(err, languagedoc){

                // I can log the expected query results...
                console.log(JSON.stringify(languagedoc, undefined, 2));
                console.log(JSON.stringify(languages, undefined, 2));
                // But as soon as i try to render, things go wrong
                res.render('test', {languages: languages, language: languagedoc});
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is the error:

```
Language.find({_user_id: userdoc._id}, {name: 1}, function(err, langua
                                    ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of null
at Promise.<anonymous>
```

The error only occurs when i try to render the page/send a response. I am puzzled! I guess my question is: why does this query seem to process correctly, but also produce an error?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I simply needed to remove the _id for the find operations

```
// This is correct
Language.find({_user_id: userdoc}, {name: 1}, function(err, languages) {
// NOT this
Language.find({_user_id: userdoc._id}, {name: 1}, function(err, languages) {
```